# Замена значения на prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Как можно изменить слово на `prolog`?
Т.е. у меня есть база знаний
`любит('Эрик',плавание)`.
Существует ли команда для изменения на `любит('Том',плавание)`?

Comment: какая версия пролога?

Comment: SWI-PROLOG 7.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы факты можно было изменять нужно определить их как динамичные, для этого используется [директива `dynamic`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(dynamic)/1). В случае в вопросе определение будет выглядеть так:

```
:-dynamic любит/2. % динамичный факт "любит" с двумя значениями
```

Изменять факты нельзя, но можно удалить один факт и добавить другой.

Для удаления используется [предикат `retract`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=retract/1), для добавления в конец - [assertz](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=assertz/1)

Их можно использовать для написания клаузы `replace_pred`, которая удалит один факт и запишет другой.

Пример реализации:

```
replace_pred(OldX,NewX) :-
    retract(любит(OldX, плавание)),
    assertz(любит(NewX, плавание)).
```

Теперь при вызове: `replace_pred('Эрик','Том')` факт `любит('Эрик',плавание)` удалится, а факт `любит('Том',плавание)` добавится.

[Пример работы](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/syFgZZcQ.pl)